# Отключение сквозного клика

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx

Есть следующий код:

```
var a = Pane()
a.setPrefSize(200.0, 200.0)
a.style = "-fx-background-color: red"
a.setOnMouseClicked { 
    println("a")
}
var b = Pane()
b.setPrefSize(100.0, 100.0)
b.style = "-fx-background-color: green"
b.setOnMouseClicked {
    println("b")
}
a.children.addAll(b)
root.children.addAll(a)
```

При нажатии на дочерний Pane срабатывает не только его событие, но и событие родительского элемента. Каким образом можно отключить этот сквозной клик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `consume` прекращает распространение события.

```
b.setOnMouseClicked {
    it.consume()
    println("b")
}
```

Comment: Лучший, спасибо